# Access data attribute value inside handlebars template

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

My HTML is like this

```
<div id="view-user-body" class="panel-body" 
     data-update-details-url="/dummyurlupdatedetails" 
     data-reset-password-url="/dummyurlresetpassword">
</div>
```

and i want to access these data attributes inside my handlebars template

```
<div class="button yellow tmargin20 buttonWidth">
    <a href="{{data-update-details-url}}" title="Update Details" role="button">Update Details</a>
</div>
<div class="button white tmargin20 buttonWidth">
    <a href="{{{data-reset-password-url}}}" title="Reset Password" role="button">Reset Password</a>
</div>
```

How i access data attribute inside my handlebars template???

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's ".attr()"

So like:

```
$('#view-user-body").attr('data-update-details-url'); // will return "/dymmyurlupdatedetails"
```

And to set them:

```
$('#view-user-body").attr('data-update-details-url', 'new text');
```

Comment: don't want to use jQuery, only handlebars